# No margins for Winter Bash popup

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

When opting out the Winter Bash the top bar popup related to snowflake looks like this for me:

> [image: Hate hats]

Is it intentional that there are no horizontal margins for popup content?

Comment: One does not simply walk away from Winter Bash.

Comment: Good point, we definitely want to be *marginalizing* people who hate hats.