# Winter Bash notification bar left padding is missing

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash

There is left padding missing for the text, but the right padding is perfect in the Winter Bash notification bar (I mark as red line in the picture):

[image]

Comment: Duplicate : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357959/no-margins-for-winter-bash-popup